# How to obtain `ApproximateReceiveCount` from an SQS message

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm using Amazon SQS. My goal is to read `ApproximateReceiveCount` attribute from [`ReceiveMessage` API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) using the Java SDK (v2.10.4, Java 11).

I tried the following code, but `message.attributes()` doesn't contain the required key:

```java
String getApproximateReceiveCount() {
    var receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/012345678910/my-example-queue")
        .build();
    var sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4576")).build();
    var response = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
    var message = response.messages().get(0);
    return message.attributes().get(MessageSystemAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_RECEIVE_COUNT);
}
```

How to go about receiving an entry for `MessageSystemAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_RECEIVE_COUNT` key, in this map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [the documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html) to `ReceiveMessage` which you linked, there is a parameter called `AttributeName.N` described as

> A list of attributes that need to be returned along with each message. These attributes include:
>
> - [...]
> - *ApproximateReceiveCount* – Returns the number of times a message has been received from the queue but not deleted.

Therefore you need to ask for the attribute in the request, for it to be available in the response. To do that  use `ReceiveMessageRequestBuilder.attributeNamesWithStrings()` method like so:

```java
String getApproximateReceiveCount() {
    var receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl("https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/012345678910/my-example-queue")
        .attributeNamesWithStrings(MessageSystemAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_RECEIVE_COUNT.toString())
        .build();
    var sqsClient = SqsClient.builder().endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:4576")).build();
    var response = sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest);
    var message = response.messages().get(0);
    return message.attributes().get(MessageSystemAttributeName.APPROXIMATE_RECEIVE_COUNT);
}
```

Note that there are two similarly named methods, which you can't use:

- `.attributeNames()` - the parameter enum doesn't list the required key,
- `.messageAttributeNames()` - corresponds to attributes sent along with the message body.

Comment: As of 2021 i used this MessageSystemAttributeName.ApproximateReceiveCount.name()